# The controller see .html page but not .jsp

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm a newbie to spring world, 
So i work on a HelloWorld example, i wrote the following simple controller:

```
Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloWorldController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView helloWorld(){

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("MVC_First_Page");
    model.addObject("msg", "hello world");

    return model;
  }
```

[image]

I'm getting the following error:

```
 Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException:
```

Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Why the intercepor can't see the MVC_First_Page.jsp page? I have changed it's extension to .html and it works.

Should i add this attributes to application.properties file?

```
  spring.mvc.view.prefix: 
  spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Comment: You need to set the prefix and suffix. https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/boot-serve-dynamic.html I wouldn't keep JSP files in the static folder however as these are clearly not static resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need Thymeleaf (since you are just experimenting), the easiest way is to have just the jsp view resolver.

You can find a good example here: https://hellokoding.com/spring-boot-hello-world-example-with-jsp/

Basically, in your code you would need to remove Thymeleaf from your `pom.xml` and add jasper dependency:

```
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Then you have to specify the view suffix in your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

And finally, you need to move the JSP file to the `src/main/webapp` directory

Comment: I should also add the following dependency to the pom.xml:                          <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>